# js - comparing 2 arrays of objects, and storing the identical and the unidentical results in new arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Made example arrays -

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: "q",
    age: 10,
    size: "M",
  },
  {
    name: "w",
    age: 10,
    size: "S",
  },
  {
    name: "e",
    age: 10,
    size: "M",
  },
];

const arr2 = [
  {
    name: "q",
    age: 10,
    size: "M",
  },
  {
    name: "w",
    age: 10,
    size: "S",
  },
  {
    name: "i",
    age: 10,
    size: "S",
  },
  {
    name: "x",
    age: 10,
    size: "S",
  },
];
```

I want to compare the first array (`arr`) to the second one (`arr2`) by specific properties in the example case `name` and `size`.

If it's a match then I want to store the results in a new array and if it's unmatched then I want to store the results in another array, so I'll get 2 arrays at the end.

What I tried -

```
   for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const { name: name1, size: size1 } = arr[i];
    const { name: name2, size: size2 } = arr2[j];

    
    if (name1 === name2 && size1 === size2) {
        x.push(arr.splice(i, 1)[0]);
        break;
    } else {
        y.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Got in x -

```
[ { name: 'q', age: 10, size: 'M' },   { name: 'w', age: 10, size: 'S' } ]
```

Got in y -

```
[ { name: 'e', age: 10, size: 'M' },
  { name: 'e', age: 10, size: 'M' } ]
```

I should get in y -

```
[ { name: 'e', age: 10, size: 'M' } ]
```

Would love to get some help

Comment: Use `push()` to add to an array, not `concat()`.

Comment: why are you indexing the strings -- shouldn't it be `name1 === name2 && size1 === size2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop cannot decide whether an element should be pushed to `y`, because not all values of `arr2` have been iterated yet. Such a push can only happen when all those `arr2` values have been considered.

As you don't remove the item from `arr` when it is pushed to `y`, it is no surprise it can be pushed a second time.

It is also problematic that you use `splice` in a loop over that same array. This means that indexes are skipped, and this could also be a source of wrong results.

One way to solve this, is to create a `Set` of the second array, of strings that uniquely define the name/size combination, for instance by joining them with a separator that will not occur in the `size` value. Then remains to iterate the first array and check if that name/size key is present in that set or not:

```js
const arr = [{name: "q",age: 10,size: "M",},{name: "w",age: 10,size: "S",},{name: "e",age: 10,size: "M",},];
const arr2 = [{name: "q",age: 10,size: "M",},{name: "w",age: 10,size: "S",},{name: "i",age: 10,size: "S",},{name: "x",age: 10,size: "S",},];

const set = new Set(arr2.map(({name, size}) => size + "/" + name));

const x = [], y = [];
for (let obj of arr) {
    (set.has(obj.size + "/" + obj.name) ? x : y).push(obj);
}

console.log("x:");
console.log(x);
console.log("y:");
console.log(y);
```